# mount point /usr/share error

Tags: partitioning, mount

I had mounted a partition in /usr/share during installation of xubuntu.Then I used Gparted to format the partition. Then whenever I boot my PC a message is displayed "press s to skip d to manually mount the device". how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit `/etc/fstab` and remove the /usr/share mount point:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

You should see a line like this:

UUID=XXXXXX   /usr/share    ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro    0   0

That is the line telling your system to mount the partition with [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) XXXX to the directory `/usr/share`. Deleting that line should solve your problem.